# Difference between bodyparser.json({type: '*/*'}) and bodyparser.encodedurl({extended: true})

Tags: javascript, body-parser

I used each in different apps and they seem to do the same thing. I am kind of new and not totally sure as to why we use one over the other. If anyone could explain that would be awesome!

Comment: default browser form submit doesn't send as json ... it sends uri encoded data. But structured json data is more convenient in many ways but requires using other request approaches like ajax

Comment: What did you try that makes you think they are the same?

Comment: @Bergi I have 2 applications in which one I am using postman and the other is already made. The one that is already live is using the .encodedurl, and works just fine. The one in development I use post man to send the request as of now and using .json instead and it seems to work the same.